# Error when call webservice using Alamofire in swift 2.3

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to swift 2.3

I am getting this ERROR when call webservice..

```
App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://)
resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can 
be configured via your app's Info.plist file.
```

Comment: <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
 <dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <true/>
 </dict>

Add this to ur plist. Please refer to above duplicate link for more help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add App Transport Security property in your project's  .plist
like this [image: ScreenShot]